# Is there a way to make the white background of an image file fully transparent in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a t-shirt image, such as this
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDHQq.jpg)

**I would like to trim out the T-Shirt from the white background and put it on top of a different image.**

I have tried giving each white pixel in the image an alpha channel. Code:

```
Future<File> getDirectory() async{
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
  File file = new File('$appDocPath/newImg');
  final bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
  var newImg = await removeWhiteBackground(bytes);
  Uint8List newPng = Uint8List.fromList(newImg);
  file.writeAsBytes(newPng);
  return file;
}

Future<List<int>> removeWhiteBackground(Uint8List bytes) async {
  final image = decodeImage(bytes);
  final pixels = image!.getBytes(format: Format.rgba);
  final length = pixels.lengthInBytes;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
    if(pixels[i] == 255 && pixels[i + 1] == 255 && pixels[i + 2] == 255) {
      pixels[i + 3] = 0;
    }
  }
  return encodePng(image);
}

void getValue() async{
  stuff = await getDirectory();
}
```

I call the `getValue` function right after I choose the Image from the phone's gallery. Then I use  the value of `stuff` for the image widget:

```
var stuff;

class CheckIt extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CheckItState createState() => new CheckItState();
}

class CheckItState extends State<CheckIt> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.file(stuff),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the end result still displays an unchanged image of the T-Shirt, with its white background.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, consider using an alternative blending mode instead of masking pixels - you might get better results that way, assuming no part of the photo's subject is white.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I have zero practical experience with Dart/Flutter)

I think the problem is that (I assume) the `Image` type is immutable, so altering `pixels` *after* you've already created your `Image image` isn't going to help: you'll need to recreate the `Image` from the modified pixels.

So change this:

```
Future<List<int>> removeWhiteBackground(Uint8List bytes) async {
  final image = decodeImage(bytes);
  final pixels = image!.getBytes(format: Format.rgba);
  final length = pixels.lengthInBytes;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
    if(pixels[i] == 255 && pixels[i + 1] == 255 && pixels[i + 2] == 255) {
      pixels[i + 3] = 0;
    }
  }
  return encodePng(image);
}
```

...to this:

```
Future<List<int>> removeWhiteBackground(Uint8List bytes) async {
  final origImage = decodeImage(bytes);
  final pixels = origImage!.getBytes(format: Format.rgba);
  final length = pixels.lengthInBytes;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
    if(pixels[i] == 255 && pixels[i + 1] == 255 && pixels[i + 2] == 255) {
      pixels[i + 3] = 0;
    }
  }

  final newImage = decodeImage(pixels);
  return encodePng(newImage );
}
```

BTW, you need to add error-handling for the cases when `decodeImage` fails.